# How to Cancel UI Full Screen in Another Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-statusbar

So I have an activity with 4 fragments, the plan is to create the first fragment full screen beyond the status bar by using `(activity as AppCompatActivity).getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)` It was a success, but then the rest of the fragments also follow this pattern.

I am trying to use `(activity as AppCompatActivity).getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE)` but it still doesn't work. instead, there is a gap between status bar and action bar now. And the layout overlap with the action bar.

I am trying to use `(activity as AppCompatActivity).getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.GONE)` but now the status bar height become double and there is an empty second line on the status bar. The layout still overlap with the action bar.

I have also set `android:fitSystemWindows="false"` in the first layout

Used `(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()` the toolbar still overlap with the items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
```

you are setting System UI Visibility on activity  that's why your all fragments are laid out full screen. Instead , you can use root view of the fragment to get laid out full screen.
If you use view Binding or data binding, you can use it like this

```
 _binding!!.root.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
```

Note above code is in Kotlin.

As, systemUiVisibility api is deprecated, we can use one liner code.

Inside OnCreateView() of the fragment which you want to laid out fully use

```
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(requireActivity().window,false)
```

And on the fragment in which you don't wan to laid out fully, just pass true

```
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(requireActivity().window,true)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing, somehow the app generalise this code `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(requireActivity().window,false)` so whether I put it true or false, it will always assume it as true, even if the fitSystemWindows set as false and has never been applied before.

Comment: Where do you put it? Inside activity or fragment? Try removing fitSystemWindows.

Comment: inside each fragment? Also binding.root.systemUiVisibility wont change the appearance of the fragment. I dont know it is too complicated and have decided to ditch this full screen layout in each fragment UI.